# Doctrine does not update FOSUserBundle User object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm encountered a weird problem.

I'm working on a Symfony 2.1 project with Doctrine 2.2 and the FOSUserBundle for user management.

I added a RequestListener, since the user can change the language of the site and I want to track the last used language of the user.

So I simply added a new property to the User Entity and then want to save the new language if has changed.

So I'm doing this in the request listener:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($event->getRequest()->getRequestFormat() !== 'html') {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->context->getToken()->getUser() instanceof \Foo\BarBundle\Entity\User) {
        $this->request = $event->getRequest();
        $this->user = $this->context->getToken()->getUser();

        if ($this->user->getCustomer() instanceof \Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Customer) {
            $this->customer = $this->user->getCustomer();

            $permission = $this->permissionService->getPermissionSafely($this->customer);

            $params = $this->request->get('_route_params');

            $language = $this->getLanguage($permission['language']['languages']);
            $locale = (strtolower($this->request->get('_locale')) === 'de') ? 'de_DE' : 'en_US';

            if ($language !== "all" && $this->request->get('_locale') !== $language) {
                $params['_locale'] = $language;

                $redirect = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($this->request->get('_route'), $params));

                $event->setResponse($redirect);
            }

            if ($this->user->getLastLanguage() !== $locale) {
                $this->user->setLastLanguage($locale);
                $this->em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
}

private function getLanguage($language)
{
    if (!isset($language['en'])) {
        return 'de';
    }
    if (!isset($language['de'])) {
        return 'en';
    }

    if ($language['en'] && !($language['de'])) {
        return 'en';
    } else if (!$language['en'] && $language['de']) {
        return 'de';
    }

    return 'all';
}
```

Important is the last `if`-conditional. If the current `$locale` is different than the last used, I want to update the user object. So there are three possible values: `de_DE`, `en_US` and `null`.

Now the weird behaviour comes in (and I don't know if it's a bug or what, but I'm confused):

It doesn't matter which value is stored in the database, it always gets updated to `en_US`.

If a user has visit the page for the first time (value `null`) and visits the site in german (value `de_DE`) it gets updated to `en_US`, but the profiler query says:

```
UPDATE `user` SET last_language = 'de_DE' WHERE id = 1
```

If a user has `last_language = 'de_DE'` and visits the site in german (`de_DE`) it gets updated to `en_US`, but the query profiler says, that there wasn't a update query. Which makes sense, because the `$locale` is the same like `$this->user->getLastLanguage()`.

What the??

I have no idea what is going on here. Has anyone experienced a similar problem? Has this something to do with the fact, that I'm modifying the user object from the security context?

**Update**: The funny thing is, if I change line

```
$locale = (strtolower($this->request->get('_locale')) === 'de') ? 'de_DE' : 'en_US';
```

to

```
$locale = (strtolower($this->request->get('_locale')) === 'de') ? 'de_DE' : 'es_US';
```

it gets updated to `es_US` event if `$locale` holds `de_DE`

Comment: It gets set to `foo` as wanted. Thing is... It's the only position where I set the `last_language` property, and the $locale variable gets out of scope since it's the end of the function. So why in gods name should it always jump back to `en_US`?

Comment: Well the thing is, that there are a lot of customers the users can be assigned to and they have different permissions (e.g. different languages the site can be viewed in). So It's basically a huge array of permissions. `$permission['language']['languages']` looks like this `'de' => true, 'en' => false` (just an example). Besides that, the `$permission` array has nothing to do with my problem, has it?

Comment: Yeah, but this is not as easy as just adding booleans, to check if something is granted, because you can also have integers or strings, even callbacks. And still this has nothing to do with the fact that Doctrine is acting crazy. Because I just want to update the last requested locale.

Comment: Because I dumped `$locale` when it updated the wrong value. `$locale` is always the correct one. It holds `de_DE` and the database says `de_DE`, but it gets updated to `en_US` but doctrine does not log a query, that would explain that.

Comment: I don't know what I should do different. I dump `$locale` right before the assignment, I even dump the user object before I flush. It states `de_DE` (also the logged query says, it UPDATES to `de_DE`) but writes `en_US` into the database.

Comment: It's just a simple setting method: `public function setLastLanguage($lastLanguage)
    {
        $this->lastLanguage = $lastLanguage;
        return $this;
    }`

Comment: Is there something like protected $lastLanguage = 'en_US' in your User entity ... meaning a default value ? What is the default locale in your symfony configuration?

Comment: Well with your last update you are actually showing that it's not doctrine introduing your problem but your code ...

Comment: Might be, but why? It's just an string and it's never saved to `$locale` but still gets written into the database. So why? And still the profiler says that it's executing the correct SQL UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary if statement will always fail because the return value of

```
$this->request->get('_locale')
```

will be :

- de_DE

but never === 'de'. Therefore if you save $locale in your entity after calling

```
$locale = (strtolower($this->request->get('_locale')) === 'de') ? 'de_DE' : 'en_US';
```

... the next time this statement fails and puts it back to 'en_US' calling ...

```
$user->setLastLanguage('en_US');
```

... in the end. Just do a better comparison like ...

```
 $locale = (strstr($locale,'de') !== false) ? 'de_DE' : 'en_US';
```

Have you tried **persist** before flushing:

```
$this->user->setLastLanguage($locale);
$this->em->flush();
```

should be ...

```
 $this->user->setLastLanguage($locale);
 $this->em->persist($this->user);
 $this->em->flush();
```

... if your user is newly created and not already managed by doctrine.

Comment: yeah well... no. I already did this. Didn't change anything. I also think (but I'm not quite sure) that the user object is already persisted when retrieving it by `$this->context->getToken()->getUser()`

Comment: The user is not persisted it's only fetched from database. persist calcuates the changeset and will then populate it to the database if flush is called. so it's not going to work without persist anyway.

Comment: That's not the complete thruth. You can just fetch a entity with `$entity = $this->em->getRepository('FooBarBundle:User')->find(1);` modify it and just call `$this->em->flush();` and the changeset is also calculated, because doctrine already manages this entity. Still, it does not solve my problem :(

Comment: This is just not right. `$this->request->get('_locale')` returns `en` or `de`. If the same language is requested like in the database the if condition where I call `setLastLanguage` will be skipped. Also I did not have the problem, that the if ternary return the wrong part, the variable `$locale` is always correct. I tried your code. Did not change anything. Also, as said multiple times: The profiles show the correct SQL statement.